# updated lifecycle event: act using watcher after dom update on specific element only

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue there's the '`updated`' lifecycle method, which is appropriate for doing things to my markup after the data is in. In my case, I'm manually nudging SVG text to align to something after its dimensions change due to new text being input.

Well, it seems like I want to use the '`watch`' block because it allows me to only run my alignment function after a *specific* property is changed, but what I really need is to use the '`updated`' event as it's got to do with the DOM and not the data - but how could it be possible to isolate and run my aligning function on *just* the one element that was edited and caused the '`updated`' to fire?

I'd rather not cause multiple adjustment functions to fire off on objects which were not even updated by the user data entry.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't watch the value which holds the text input and run your alignment function then?

Comment: The truth is, I am very much a beginner at this. But the reasoning I have is how Vue behaves: (it says also in documentation), the watch properties are concerned with data and update is concerned with the markup.. so what ends up happening is, my alignment function is a 'key behind' the input. It runs the alignment, *before* the markup is rendered. So when it aligns, it does this using previous rendering. Therefore, I need to hook into the event which is concerned with the markup.
Basically, I can paste in all kinds of text and it won't align because watch sees data and not the DOM.

Comment: I could use a timeout, but I feel that it is not proper and would cause all kinds of issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The watch properties are concerned with data and update is concerned with the markup.. so what ends up happening is, my alignment function is a 'key behind' the input. It runs the alignment, before the markup is rendered. So when it aligns, it does this using previous rendering. Therefore, I need to hook into the event which is concerned with the markup.

Use `Vue.nextTick(() => { /* code you were executing */ })`:

[Docs:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

> #### Vue.nextTick( [callback, context] )
>
> - **Arguments:**
>
>   - `{Function} [callback]`
>   - `{Object} [context]`
> - **Usage:**
>
>   Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle.
>   Use it immediately after you've changed some data to wait for the DOM
>   update.
>
>   ```js
>     // modify data
>     vm.msg = 'Hello'
>     // DOM not updated yet
>      Vue.nextTick(function () {
>      // DOM updated
>     })
>
>     // usage as a promise (2.1.0+, see note below)
>     Vue.nextTick()
>     .then(function () {
>       // DOM updated
>     })
>   ```

So instead of:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // ...
  watch: {
    someProperty() {
      someUpdateCode();
    }
  }
})
```

Do:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // ...
  watch: {
    someProperty() {
      Vue.nextTick(() => { someUpdateCode(); });
    }
  }
})
```

## Comments: Is the new javascript syntax world-wide?

Yes, those are [**arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Its pretty standard JavaScript syntax. It comes from ES6 (ECMAScript 2017) version.

Basically the code `Vue.nextTick(() => { someUpdateCode(); });` is the same as: `Vue.nextTick(function () { someUpdateCode(); }.bind(this));`

Roughly speaking, `(abc) => { code }` is the same as `function(abc) { code }.bind(this)`. The `.bind(this)` part is important and frequently overlooked. Arrow functions retain the original context's `this`, whereas `function(){}`s have their specific `this` (which is modified by whoever calls that function - via `functionName.call()` or `functionName.apply()`), the `.bind()` is to retain the original context's `this` inside the `function`.

Comment: Is the new javascript syntax world-wide ? Can you please expand the 'Vue.nextTick(() => { someUpdateCode(); });' to dinosaur script for me to understand ? :)

Comment: Bravo, bravo sir it works! Great answer and a contribution to my growing knowledge!
I cannot overstate my pure delight at how well it works, I can copy/paste, undo, it's instantly responsive.
* a lot of development I do (not this though) is for Adobe ExtendScript, where we use ES3 syntax (O_o) - so ES6 is going to be a journey for me yet!

Answer (score 0):

Do it via Vue’s Updated method.
In order to run a specific function based on some specific property change, you can introduce a helping variable that tells you if your specific property is changed.

> how could it be possible to isolate and run my aligning function on just the one element that was edited and caused the 'updated' to fire?

Create a Boolean property and bind it to your element in such a way that when an element is changed the Boolean property is to be set to True and in ‘Updated’ method, just use an if condition on that Boolean property such that when it’s true, execute your alignment function and reset that Boolean property to false.

Comment: The problem with 'updated' is it would do the alignment before I needed it to happen. I suppose the same could be avoided via the nextTick function though. I'm too over that particular exercise but here is my codepen which used the accepted answer's technique: https://codepen.io/VHall/pen/BrdwLz?editors=1010

Comment: Yes you are right. In your particular use case, the nextTick is good to go. in your codepen example, Mounted method, you can do the v.adjustAllText() via the nextTick instead of doing it in setTimeout, and to be on safe side, you can call as many recursive nextTicks (i usually do this when data is binded to array of unknown size) like    Vue.nextTick(function () {
        Vue.nextTick(function () {
         v.adjustAllText();
        });
      });

Comment: nextTick is better approach. Just to add up on this, sometimes if your dom is updated by another third party js library for example jqGrid and you are hosting your dom in the context of VUE then just one NextTick will not work. In such case call NextTick nested within the NextTick calls. such as   
 Vue.nextTick()
  .then(function () {
    // DOM not yet fully updated
  Vue.nextTick()
   .then(function () {
   Vue.nextTick()
    .then(function () {
   // DOM updated
    })
   })
  })