# Previous and current data in Vue life hooks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, vuejs2, hook

How can I get previous and current data in updated life hook (similar to React)? I want to scroll elements list to the very bottom and to this I need:

- already rendered updated DOM (so I want to use updated hook to calculate scroll)
- information whether scroll or not (scroll only when number of current
  elements is bigger than previous).

I figured something like this:

```
  name: "list",
  props: ["elements"],
  data() {
    return {
      scrollBottom: false
    };
  },
  updated() {
    if (this.scrollBottom) {
      window.scroll(0, this.$root.$el.scrollHeight); /* full window / app height list*/
    }
  },
  watch: {
    elements(current, prev) {
      this.scrollBottom = current.length > prev.length;
    }
  }
```

I’m not sure if this is a „right” approach but Vue life hooks don't receive any information about previous data. Can I do it better? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**
I found this helpful topic: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410249/updated-lifecycle-event-act-using-watcher-after-dom-update-on-specific-element). Apparently, the best way to handle this is to use this.$nextTick method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, In Vue [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated), They mentioned as below:

**updated Hook**

> The component’s DOM will have been updated when this hook is called, so you can perform DOM-dependent operations here. However, in most cases, you should avoid changing the state inside the hook. To react to state changes, it’s usually better to use a computed property or watcher instead.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I could write smth like this:

```
{
  name: "list",
  props: ["elements"],
  data() {
    return {
      // scrollBottom no needs here
    };
  },
  methods: {
     scrollToBottom() {        
       window.scroll(0, this.$root.$el.scrollHeight); /* full window / app height list*/
    }
  },
  watch: {
    elements(current, prev) {
      if (current.length > prev.length)
         this.scrollToBottom();
    }
  }
}
```

In watch method use `scrollToBottom` directly

Comment: Sounds good, doesn't work :) - DOM isn't updated yet, so scroll value will be wrong. This is the reason why I want to use updated() hook.